# How to use Firebase with AppStudio for ArcGIS?

Tags: javascript, firebase, qt-creator, arcgis

I'm trying to develop a mobile app with **appstudio for arcgis** which use Qt Creator Qml and javascript languages. I want to know if it's possible to integrate **Firebase** on Appstudio? I cannot find a SDK for this.